# How to Pass Through SQL Wildcards for a Javascript URL?

Tags: javascript

I have a route in my web application with a query such as the following:

```
SELECT * FROM [Example].[dbo].[Table] 
WHERE (name LIKE query_string 
OR pm_prod_domain LIKE query_string)
```

And the url is like the following with node.js

```
router.get('/getExampleTableStuff/getInformation/:query_string
```

I call AJAX like so with SQL wildcards to get all the data from the table

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: '/getExampleTableStuff/getInformation/%%',
        headers : { "content-type":"application/json"}
    }).done(function (results) { console.log(results) });
```

This results in an error due to the `%` in the url. How do I fix this issue so that I can pass wildcards through and get all the data from my table? I am using squel library to generate the SQL in my backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [encodeURI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) function like follows and the issue will be resolved:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: encodeURI('/getExampleTableStuff/getInformation/%%'),
        headers : { "content-type":"application/json"}
    }).done(function (results) { console.log(results) });
```

Comment: Shouldn't you only URL-encode the value, not the entire URL?  Seems like URL-encoding the slashes may cause issues.  Also, this looks suspiciously suceptible to SQL injection...

Comment: @David This is part of the reason I posted this as a question even though I had a working solution. Wanted to see if anyone had a better answer to solve this issue :)